# Build a graph that works with variable batch size using Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I use tf.placeholders() ops for feeding variable batch size of input which are 2D tensors and use the feed mechanism to supply different values for those tensors when I call run().
I got

> TypeError: 'Tensor' object is not iterable.

Following is my code:

```
with graph.as_default():
    train_index_input = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=(None, window_size))
    train_embeddings = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([vocabulary_size, embedding_dimension], -1.0, 1.0))
    embedding_input = [tf.nn.embedding_lookup(train_embeddings, x) for x in train_index_input]
    ......
    ......
```

As I can not see the content of the tensor "train_index_input" without running the graph,  so the error of "'Tensor' object is not iterable" raises for the code:

```
embedding_input = [tf.nn.embedding_lookup(train_embeddings, x) for x in train_index_input]
```

What I want to obtain is an embedding matrix "embedding_input" that is of shape [batch_size, embedding_dimension] where `batch_size` is not fixed. Do I have to define a new operation in Tensorflow for embedding lookup for 2D tensors? Or any other ways to do it?Thanks

Answer (score 8):

You're trying to do a python-level list comprehension (`for x in train_index_input`) over a Tensorflow placeholder.  That won't work - Python has no idea what's inside a tf object.

To accomplish a batch embedding lookup, what you can do is just flatten your batch:

```
train_indexes_flat = tf.reshape(train_index_input, [-1])
```

run it through embedding lookup:

```
looked_up_embeddings = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(train_embeddings, train_indexes_flat)
```

and then reshape it back into the right groups:

```
embedding_input = tf.reshape(looked_up_embeddings, [-1, window_size])
```

Comment: I have a similar question, The shape of input is `[batch_size, maxstep, 50, 50]`, and I want to use a certain cnn to make it become `[batch_size, maxstep, 5 * 5 * 32]`, but it's difficult to build the graph without loop. Is there any idea? Thank you very much.