# tensorflow stacked LSTM: "'Tensor' object is not iterable"

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network

I'm trying to build a stacked LSTM RNN in tensorflow with number of layers equal to `num_layers`, and each layer has cells equal to `lstm_state_dim`. Following is the code for generating the computational graph for the same.

```py
lstm_cells = []
for _ in range(num_layers):
        lstm_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(lstm_state_dim)
        lstm_cells.append(lstm_cell)
    stacked_lstm_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell(lstm_cells)    
    self.lstm_outputs,_ = \
    tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(stacked_lstm_cell,state_seq,\
                      initial_state = \
                      tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMStateTuple\
                      (tf.zeros([self.num_layers,self.batch_size,self.lstm_state_dim]),\
                       tf.zeros([self.num_layers,self.batch_size,self.lstm_state_dim])),\
                      dtype = tf.float32)
```

I get the error "TypeError: 'Tensor' object is not iterable." for the following lines of code

```py
    self.lstm_outputs,_ = \
    tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(stacked_lstm_cell,state_seq,\
                      initial_state = \
                      tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMStateTuple\
                      (tf.zeros([self.num_layers,self.batch_size,self.lstm_state_dim]),\
                       tf.zeros([self.num_layers,self.batch_size,self.lstm_state_dim])),\
                      dtype = tf.float32)
```

What am I missing? The solution proposed in [Tensor Flow - LSTM - 'Tensor' object not iterable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40464178/tensor-flow-lstm-tensor-object-not-iterable)  is not relevant, despite the matching title. The first reason being that I want the `state_is_tuple` to be set to be True. Secondly, I want to use placeholders in order to input the LSTM start cell states.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tensor Flow - LSTM - 'Tensor' object not iterable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40464178/tensor-flow-lstm-tensor-object-not-iterable)

Comment: @TusharGupta the solution proposed there isn't what I am looking for..even the issues aren't the same