# TensorFlow Increase Batch Size mid experiment

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-ml

I am looking to replicate some of the behavior in this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1711.00489.pdf) "don't decay the learning rate, increase the batch size" and I am wondering if there is a simple approach to increase the batch size within a GCMLE experiment.  I have a custom estimator and I am trying to think of any ways to adjust the batch size within the experiment.  I realize that I could run with one batch size for a certain number of epochs and then load this saved graph and kick off a subsequent experiment, but I am wondering if there are any other options to update the batch size within the same experiment?

Answer (score 2):

Setting up your graph to support a variable batch size is pretty easy, just use a `None` in the shape of the first dimension. Take a look at this article:

[Build a graph that works with variable batch size using Tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33884978/build-a-graph-that-works-with-variable-batch-size-using-tensorflow)

Then you feed in any size batch at every `sess.run(train_op, feed_dict=[X:data, Y:labels])` where the first dimension of `X`, your batch, is variable length.

It pretty much just works as you'd expect.

Example graph structure wiht variable batch size:

```py
X = tf.placeholder("float", [None, num_input])
Y = tf.placeholder("float", [None, num_classes])
```

In general, you're allowed to have 1 unknown dimension in your tensors. Tensorflow will infer that dimension based on the actual data you pass it at runtime.

In this example, in your first iterations your data shape might be `[10, 784]` (batches of 10), and in later iterations maybe your shape becomes `[50, 784]` (batches of 50). The rest of your graph setup will work without change.

Comment: Thanks! It definitely makes sense for how to do this if I was using sess.run -- however, I am using learn_runner.run() and running a tensorflow experiment with a custom estimator like this example here: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/tree/master/census/customestimator/trainer. The graph is already set up to support variable batch sizes, but I pass a single batch size (can be anything) at the beginning of the experiment. So, what I am struggling with is I can't find any way to adjust the experiments batch size after X epochs or Y iterations as you describe

Comment: You can have two (or multiple) `learn_runner.run` statements one after the other. The weights would stay in memory and you can increase the batch size parameter.

Comment: @UtkarshSinha learn_runner.run starts a new process on the provided port, so calling it twice will fail with "Port already in use"

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to set `delay_workers_by_global_step=True` in the [constructor](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.2/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/learn/Experiment) to `Experiment`.

The reason this works is because the effective batch size is `batch_size` * `num_workers`. So if you delay the start of other workers, your batch size will gradually increase.

Of course, your throughput will be correspondingly lower in the early phases.

If you directly want to control the batch_size, you will have to effectively replicate the behavior of `learn_runner.run` in your own code. That wouldn't be too bad, except for the fact that deep down in `experiment.py`, it starts a server which, AFAICT, cannot be disabled.

Comment: Interesting approach! What would num_workers be equal to under the default setting for say a BASIC_GPU run? The documentation says that the default is False and it seems that the delay would be based on time instead of steps? Then when delay_workers_by_global_step is set to True, how often would the num_workers increase? I'm trying to get a sense for how much larger the batch size would get over the steps.